# Require.js module(node-fetch) load for contex error

Tags: javascript, web, module, requirejs, node-fetch

I'm making a website and I'm struggling with Require.js.
I want to require `node-fetch` package:

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

// Getting avatar of random discord user
const token = process.env.TOKEN;

async function fetchit() {
  const response = await fetch(`https://discord.com/api/v9/users/410902667318001684`, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bot ${token}`
    }
  })
  if (!response.ok) throw new Error(`Error status code: ${response.status}`)
  else{
   let obj = await response.json()
   console.log(obj.avatar)
  }
  
}
fetchit()
```

and I get this error:

```
Error: Module name "node-fetch" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
```

I tried using `const fetch = require(['node-fetch'])`, but I got another error:

```
Error: Script error for "node-fetch"
https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
```

This is my HTML script tag: `<script data-main="script.js" src="require.js">`

How can I fix this and get it working?

I use node-fetch@2.6.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can't** load `node-fetch` using Require.JS.

Require.js is a module loader for **AMD modules**.

`node-fetch` is a **Common.JS module** (which also depends on APIs provided by Node.js which aren't available in browsers).

AMD and Common.JS modules are very different module formats. Their loaders aren't compatible even if they do both use a function named `require` (they use **different** functions named `require`).

(As of version 3, `node-fetch` has been [converted to an ECMAScript module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch#loading-and-configuring-the-module) but still depends on Node.js and is still not compatible with Require.JS).

---

Use the browser-native [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) instead. `node-fetch` is a library designed to be compatible with it so you can use the same API in browsers and Node.js.